# Matrix in C++ (print middle row, print middle col, etc)

Tags: c++, matrix

I keep getting segmentation error. Any help would be appreciated. I am a student so please go easy on me. Thank you.

Background: 
I have to print the matrix, the sum of all the elements, show the upper half, show the lower half, print the middle row, print the middle column. 
The dimensions of the matrix are read in followed by N*M values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void printMatrix(int** matrix, int n, int m)
{
     cout << "Printed matrix: " << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
            for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
            {
                    cout << matrix[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl;
    }
};

void getSum(int** matrix, int n, int m)
{
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
            for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
            {
                    sum += matrix[i][j];
            }
    }
    cout << "The sum of all numbers is: " << sum << endl;
 };

void printUpper(int** matrix, int n, int m)
{
    if(n != m)
    {
            cout << "The matrix is not square.\n";
            return;
    }

    cout << "The upper half of the array: \n";
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
            for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
            {
                    if(j<i)
                    {
                            cout << "\t";
                            continue;
                    }
                    cout << matrix[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl;
    }
}

void printMiddleRow(int** matrix, int n, int m)
{
    if(n%2==0)
    {
            cout << "Error! The number of rows is even. Cannnot print the middle.\n";
            return;
    }
    cout << "The middle row: " << endl;
    int mid = n/2;
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
            cout << matrix[mid][i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
};

void printMiddleCol(int** matrix, int n, int m)
{
    if(m%2==0)
    {
            cout << "Error! The number of columns is even. Cannot print the middle.\n";
            return;
    }

    cout << "The middle column: \n";
    int mid = m/2;

    for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
            cout << matrix[i][mid] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc<0)//checks to make sure user inputs dimensions of array
            cout << "Error! More command line arguments are required.\n";

    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    int m = atoi(argv[2]);

    int** matrix = new int*[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
            matrix[i] = new int[m];
    }

    int cur = 3;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
            for(int j=0; j<m; j++)
            {
                    matrix[i][j] = atoi(argv[cur]);
                    cur++;
            }
    }

    cout << "Please choose from the following options: \n";
    cout << "1. Print the matrix.\n";
    cout << "2. Sum all of the elements.\n";
    cout << "3. Show the upper half.\n";
    cout << "4. Show the middle row.\n";
    cout << "5. Show the middle column.\n";

    int choice;
    cout << "Enter selection: ";
    cin >> choice;

    switch(choice)
    {
            case(1):
                    printMatrix(matrix, n, m);
                    break;
            case(2):
                    getSum(matrix, n, m);
                    break;
            case(3):
                    printUpper(matrix, n, m);
                    break;
            case(4):
                    printMiddleRow(matrix, n, m);
                    break;
            case(5):
                    printMiddleCol(matrix, n, m);
                    break;
            default:
                    cout << "Invalid selection. Goodbye.\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To a large extent, your code is written in C-like style, but it is C++, and will not be accepted by a C compiler.  Tags edited.

Comment: Whoops I meant C++

Comment: `if(argc<0)` meaninglessness

Comment: in printMiddleCol, the for loop should use n instead of m. that is, should be for(int i=0; i<n; i++)

Comment: Can you run the code in a debugger to determine where the segfault is happening? It might help narrow down the search for the error.

Comment: Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the printMiddleCol function, the range for the "for loop" is given 0 to m, it should be 0 to n. Please correct it.